# Spark RDD : sorting an array of numbers

Tags: apache-spark

I would like to use Spark scala API for this. I have data in the following format:

```
id1   val1, val2, val3
id2   val1, val2, val3, val4, val5, val6
id3   val1, val2, val3, val4
```

all vals are integers and I would like the result to be sorted. For example, for the following i/p

```
1   100, 20, 150
10  50, 1000, 2, 400
```

the result should be:

```
1   20, 100, 150
10  2, 50, 400, 1000
```

Any help would be great!

Here is the code to read the file:

```
val dummy_data = sc.textFile("pato/to/file").map(line => ((line.split("\t"))(0), (line.split("\t"))(1).split(",")))
dummy_data.collect()
```

The above code gives o/p as:
Array[(String, Array[String])] = Array((100,Array(5, 2, 4, 3, 1)), (1000,Array(14, 11, 10, 12, 13)))

Now how do I cast this dummy_data appropriately so that I can sort the values in the 2nd element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`mapValues` with `sorted` should do the trick:

- Scala:

  ```scala
  sc.parallelize(Seq(
      (1, Seq("100", "20", "150")), (10, Seq("50", "1000", "2", "400"))))
    .mapValues(_.map(_.toInt).sorted)
    .take(2)
  //  Array[(Int, Seq[Int])] = 
  //    Array((1,List(20, 100, 150)), (10,List(2, 50, 400, 1000)))
  ```
- Python:

  ```py
  (sc.parallelize([(1, ("100", "20", "150")), (10, ("50", "1000", "2", "400"))])
    .mapValues(lambda xs: sorted(int(x) for x in xs))
    .take(2))
  ## [(1, [20, 100, 150]), (10, [2, 50, 400, 1000])]
  ```

Comment: When I read it from the file using sc.textFile, it comes out as org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[(String, Seq[String])] and not as org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[(String, Seq[Int])], what would be the most efficient way to cast it properly -- to Seq(Int)?

Comment: Just replace `_.sorted` with `_.map(_.toInt).sorted`

Comment: Updated the question.